# Volume of half an ellipsoid

Tags: 3d, volume, ellipsoids

I want to calculate the volume of the solid defined as follows.

$$ K := \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 + 3z^2 \le 4, z > 0 \right\} $$

I know that this is a half solid ellipsoid and that the volume of an ellipsoid is calculated by $\frac{4}{3}\pi abc$. Thus, for the whole ellipsoid, we should get the volume $\frac{32\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$ but should I then divide this by $2$ as well since it is given that $z>0$ on $K$?

I saw a similar task where this was not done and I don't know if it is me who is wrong about dividing it by two, or if a mistake was made in the solution to the task.

Comment: Your volume for the entire ellipsoid (an oblate spheroid in this case) _enclosed_ by $ \ K \ $ appears to be correct, and you do want half of that as the volume of the portion "above" the $  \ xy-$plane.

Comment: Thank you! @boojum

Comment: $$\int _0^{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}}\int _0^{2 \pi }\int _0^{\sqrt{4-3 z^2}}\rho\ d\rho d\phi dz=\frac{16 \pi }{3 \sqrt{3}}$$